# Is there any way to extract variables that are being passed to a particular function as parameters in a given c code?

Tags: c, variables, gdb, code-analysis, information-retrieval

Is there any way to extract variables that are being passed to a particular function as parameters in a given c code?

For an example,

```
main()
{
int a = 10;
float b = 2.0f;

funcA(a,b);

}
```

Need is to extract the information that **variable a & variable b** are passed to funcA in a given C code.

Is there a way to extract these information using gdb and it's function breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

when you are in any function typing `frame` will give you parameters information of function.

Below are some other commands you can use to get to know more about local variables and parameters.

`info locals`
`frame`
`info args`

more [gdb](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Enewhall/unixhelp/gdbcommands.html) commands

sample :

```
(gdb) b main                                                                                                                      
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x40053e.                                                                                       
Breakpoint 2 at 0x40053e: file main.c, line 6.                                                                                    
(gdb) r                                                                                                                           
Starting program: /home/a.out                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                  
Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:6                                                                                                 
6           int a = 10;                                                                                                           
(gdb) n                                                                                                                           
7           float b = 2.0f;                                                                                                       
(gdb) info locals                                                                                                                 
a = 10 
b = 0                                                                                                                             
x = 0                                                                                                                             
(gdb) frame                                                                                                                       
#0  main () at main.c:7                                                                                                           
7           float b = 2.0f;                                                                                                       
(gdb) next                                                                                                                        
9           int x = funcA(a,b);                                                                                                   
(gdb) step                                                                                                                        
funcA (a=10, b=2) at main.c:16                                                                                                    
16          int sum = 0;                                                                                                          
(gdb) frame                                                                                                                       
#0  funcA (a=10, b=2) at main.c:16                                                                                                
16          int sum = 0;                                                                                                          
(gdb) info args                                                                                                                   
a = 10                                                                                                                            
b = 2                                                                                                                             
(gdb) info locals                                                                                                                 
sum = 0                                                                                                                           
(gdb) p a                                                                                                                         
$1 = 10                                                                                                                           
(gdb) print b                                                                                                                     
$2 = 2                                                                                                                            
(gdb)
```